# culling equivalent Enigma keys for short messages

Tags: enigma

The following for-loop iterates over all possible keys for an M3 Enigma for three selected rotors:

```
for start_pos_left in A..Z:
    for start_pos_middle in A..Z:
        for ring_middle in 1..26:
            for start_pos_right in A..Z:
                for ring_right in 1..26:
```

For the middle and right-most rotors we need to know their start position and their ring setting.  For the left-most rotor we need only know its start position as it never 'knocks' another wheel.

A computer-age attack on the Enigma (James J Gillogly. Ciphertext-only Cryptanalysis of Enigma. Cryptologia. 19(4) 405-412.) ignores the plugboard and iterates over the rotor settings, using [Index-of-Coincidence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Index_of_coincidence) to filter the likely settings.  This is the attack I am trying to speed up.  Here is [my own implementation](http://williamedwardscoder.tumblr.com/post/145830743193/my-attack-on-the-enigma-cipher-machine) (using max freq rather than IC).

However, for short messages ([real Enigma messages](https://enigma.hoerenberg.com/index.php?cat=M4%20Project%202006&page=Publication) had a maximum of 320 letters for naval, and 250 for army and airforce messages), many of these keys are identical.

Here are some duplicate keys that turn a certain test message into identical ciphertext:

```
<A G,1 H,23> is dup of <A F,26 H,23>
<A G,1 I,24> is dup of <A F,26 I,24>
<A G,1 J,25> is dup of <A F,26 J,25>
<A G,1 K,26> is dup of <A F,26 K,26>
<A G,1 L,1> is dup of <A F,26 L,1>
<A G,1 M,2> is dup of <A F,26 M,2>
<A G,1 N,3> is dup of <A F,26 N,3>
<A G,1 O,4> is dup of <A F,26 O,4>
<A G,1 P,5> is dup of <A F,26 P,5>
<A G,1 Q,6> is dup of <A F,26 Q,6>
<A G,26 R,7> is dup of <A F,25 R,7>
<A G,26 S,8> is dup of <A F,25 S,8>
<A G,26 T,9> is dup of <A F,25 T,9>
<A G,26 U,10> is dup of <A F,25 U,10>
<A G,26 V,11> is dup of <A F,25 V,11>
<A H,1 R,7> is dup of <A F,25 R,7>
<A H,1 S,8> is dup of <A F,25 S,8>
<A H,1 T,9> is dup of <A F,25 T,9>
<A H,1 U,10> is dup of <A F,25 U,10>
<A H,1 V,11> is dup of <A F,25 V,11>
<A H,2 H,23> is dup of <A F,26 H,23>
<A H,2 I,24> is dup of <A F,26 I,24>
<A H,2 J,25> is dup of <A F,26 J,25>
<A H,2 K,26> is dup of <A F,26 K,26>
<A H,2 L,1> is dup of <A F,26 L,1>
<A H,2 M,2> is dup of <A F,26 M,2>
<A H,2 N,3> is dup of <A F,26 N,3>
<A H,2 O,4> is dup of <A F,26 O,4>
<A H,2 P,5> is dup of <A F,26 P,5>
<A H,2 Q,6> is dup of <A F,26 Q,6>
<A I,2 R,7> is dup of <A F,25 R,7>
<A I,2 S,8> is dup of <A F,25 S,8>
<A I,2 T,9> is dup of <A F,25 T,9>
<A I,2 U,10> is dup of <A F,25 U,10>
...
```

(In this example, the middle wheel is `wheel II`, which has a [notch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enigma_rotor_details#Turnover_notch_positions) at `E`.  The leftmost wheel is `III` and the rightmost wheel is `I`.)

How can you iterate over just canonical keys given you know the length of the message?

Comment: The number of key-pairs that turn *some* test message into the same ciphertext is vastly larger than the number of key-pairs that turn *all* valid messages into the same ciphertexts. It is the former you are looking for or the latter?

Comment: @otus The former.  *We know the length of the message*.  For a given message length, which combination of settings are equivalent?  How can you iterate just the canonical (i.e. distinct) settings that are different?  (And, ideally, also how can you iterate the settings that are equivalent to another setting?).  Note that there is *no plugboard* in this problem.

Comment: Ok, so the keys which are equivalent for a particular predetermined message, or those for which some message of that length exists that results in equal ciphertext?

Comment: @otus in the stated problem, the settings that are equivalent for a particular message length are equivalent for all messages with that same length.

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but why would that be? E.g. two keys can substitute an initial A to X, but an initial B to two different ciphertext characters.

Comment: @otus you made me double-check :)  I have just generated a random plaintext with a random plugboard, and encrypted it with the same rotor settings as the example above.  The same pattern of dups occurs.  I have repeated this several times.  Empirically, the equivalence of the rotor settings is a function of the message length and notches rather than the plugboard.  Thx for making me double check! :)

Comment: Heh, sorry about the extra work, I guess that makes the question unambiguous then.

Comment: @otus np, hopefully it also makes it interesting ;)

Comment: I disagree with the closure. This is not (just) a programming question, but whether and how such equivalent keys can be identified and non-equivalent keys listed.

Comment: The question seems to be centered about the programming part of the problem. If there is a cryptographically interresting problem at its core, which you want to discuss, I suggest taking it to the chat. In order to reopening, the question should be edited to actually be about the problem and not implementation details.